# Why is todo-mvp-dagger, not todo-mvvm-dagger?

Tags: android, mvvm, mvp, dagger, android-architecture

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/

In the Android architecture blueprint, why is dagger based on the mvp architecture rather than the MVVM architecture? Is it because it is not suitable for the MVVM architecture? Or other reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Dagger is suitable for any architecture, because it's not an architectural dependant  component. It's a dependency injection library. I don't know why the blueprint sample doesn't include an `MVVM-Dagger` implementation.

Here's some sample usage of dagger with `MVVM` architecture.

Here's a `Module` which provides `ViewModel` and other few objects.

```
@Module(includes = {
        RecyclerViewModule.class,
        ActivityModule.class
})
class MainActivityModule {

    private final MenuAdapter.Callback menuAdapterCallback;

    MainActivityModule(MenuAdapter.Callback menuAdapterCallback) {
        this.menuAdapterCallback = menuAdapterCallback;
    }

    @Provides
    MainActivityViewModel provideMainActivityViewModel(
            FragmentActivity fragmentActivity,
            MainActivityViewModelFactory factory
    ) {

        return ViewModelProviders.of(fragmentActivity, factory)
                .get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
    }


    @Provides
    MenuAdapter.Callback provideMenuAdapterCallback() {
        return menuAdapterCallback;
    }

    @Provides
    MainActivityViewModelFactory provideViewModelFactory(MenuAdapter menuAdapter) {
        return new MainActivityViewModelFactory(menuAdapter);
    }


}
```

and the corresponding component

```
@Component(modules = MainActivityModule.class)
public interface MainActivityComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

and the injection of the component.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseAppCompatActivity implements MenuAdapter.Callback {


    @Inject
    MainActivityViewModel viewModel;

    @Inject
    DividerItemDecoration divider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DaggerMainActivityComponent.builder()
                .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
                .mainActivityModule(new MainActivityModule(this))
                .build()
                .inject(this);

        binding.include.rvMenu.addItemDecoration(divider);

        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);

    }


}
```

You can get the full project from [here](https://github.com/theapache64/livedata_transformation_example). It's a simple example of  `MVVM + Dagger2 + Retrofit + RxJava + DataBinding` project. Feel free to clone/download to run the project.